CSS writing-mode and transform Not Working in Emails– How do i apply a vertical text in emails?
I'm trying to apply a CSS effect to display text with a vertical orientation in an HTML email. The following CSS works perfectly in browsers, but when viewed in Microsoft Outlook, the writing-mode and transform properties do not render as expected.
What do you think seems to be the problem? what are other alternatives that I could do?
<div
style="
    height: 100%;

    text-align: center;
    width: fit-content;

    max-height: 90pt;

    overflow-y: hidden; /* Hides the overflowing text */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    display: inline-block;

    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
"
>
    <p
        style="
        color: red;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        width: fit-content;
        max-height: 90pt;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        display: inline-block;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        "
    >
        This should be vertically aligned
    </p>
</div>

I have tried other solutions such as using writing-mode: tb-rl and also an attempt to use VML but to no avail.
UPDATE 1
I was able to rotate the text with using something like this, the problem with this one is it the width doesnt really adjust well based on the line breaks,
<td rowspan="2" style="mso-rotate: 90">
  <span style="color: red">
    <p>This should be vertically aligned</p>
  </span>
</td>

Other attempt that I have made is using layout-flow:horizontal inside a span like the example below, the height automatically adjust based on the longest word but it seems like line-break does not apply at all since i tried adding <br/>
<td rowspan="2">
  <span style="color: red" style="layout-flow: horizontal">
    <p>This should be vertically aligned</p>
  </span>
</td>

UPDATE 2
I was able to do a work around now to handle the sizing of the width by manually adding <br/> tags for every word. The only issue with this now is that it doesn't look good in some cases like when a word is too long or there are a lot of short words, so here is an example of my current code now. I might do it for every two words instead, but still its not completely fool proof
<td rowspan="2" style="mso-rotate: 90">
  <span style="color: red">
    <p>This <br/> should <br/> be <br/> vertically <br/> aligned</p>
  </span>
</td>



HTML email is a disaster, with little support for modern CSS — especially in Outlook. Have a look at CSS support charts for HTML email.

"but when viewed in Microsoft Outlook, the writing-mode and transform properties do not render as expected" Yep. When you're used to writing HTML + CSS for modern web browsers, writing HTML + CSS for email clients is a world of pain.

MS Outlook Windows is a totally different beast.
However it does have various alternative ways of doing things.
Try mso-text-orientation: vertical. Alternatively you can put a number in there - I've never tried, but perhaps the number would be for degrees, e.g. mso-text-orientation: 180
I would put it on the <p>, e.g.
<p style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;mso-text-orientation: vertical">
    This should be vertically aligned
</p>


Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, the code you provided didn't work, but it did point me in the right direction. I was able to make it rotate by using mso-rotate: -90 instead based on this other post link. The only issue now is that it doesn't seem to adjust the height.

you can put a different height just for Outlook with mso-height-alt: 100px; or use conditional mso

I was able to adjust the height by using plain css, the problem now with mso-rotate it doesnt really follow the new width of the rotated element, I've also tried other attempt such as layout-flow but the problem with this now is it doesnt really allow any line breaks or maybe im just doing line break wrong,

<td height="200" style="mso-rotate: 90"> works with style="mso-rotate: 90". You can mso conditional that, or I think having style="mso-rotate: 90; height: auto;" should fix it for other emial clients

yeah I was able to set the height using css, but the problem now with it is that the width doesn't adjust well based on the line breaks of the words, so there are cases where when the rotated words are too long it overflows outside the container horizontally.

okay so I was able to do a workaround regarding the width issue by adding a <br/> tag for every word, but im not sure yet if there are any better approach other than this since there are cases where a single word is too long and other similar issues like that.
